how to understand pose slam computation of likelihood?
I am reading "A Tutorial on Graph-Based SLAM",a famous graph SLAM turorial,
in the formula （2）：
The log-likelihood lij of a measurement zij is therefore
lij ∝ [zij − ẑij (xi, xj )]T Ωij [zij − ẑij (xi , xj )].
I wonder how this is implemented in reality, for example, we have a 2D robot equipped with odometry and LiDAR sensors. The robot can detect the same landmark using lidar sensor, and detect their relative movement.

Odometry Measurement (zij_odom):   zij_odom = [Δx, Δy, Δθ]^T

LiDAR

Measurement (zij_lidar):  zij_lidar = [r, θ]^T

then we have:

Predicted Measurements: Predicted Odometry Measurement (ẑij_odom):
This is calculated based on the estimated poses of nodes i and j.
Predicted LiDAR Measurement (ẑij_lidar): This is calculated based on
the estimated poses of the robot and the landmark. Odometry

Information Matrix (Ω_odom):

Ω_odom = [
[1/σ_x^2, 0, 0],
[0, 1/σ_y^2, 0],
[0, 0, 1/σ_θ^2] ]

LiDAR Information Matrix (Ω_lidar):

Ω_lidar = [
[1/σ_r^2, 0],
[0, 1/σ_θ^2] ]


Calculating the Log-Likelihood:
For each measurement type (odometry and LiDAR), we calculate the log-likelihood as follows:
Odometry:

log_likelihood_odom = -0.5 * [zij_odom - ẑij_odom]^T * Ω_odom * [zij_odom - ẑij_odom]

LiDAR:

log_likelihood_lidar = -0.5 * [zij_lidar - ẑij_lidar]^T * Ω_lidar * [zij_lidar - ẑij_lidar]

Total Log-Likelihood:
The total log-likelihood for a particular measurement can be obtained by summing the log-likelihoods from both odometry and LiDAR:

log_likelihood_total = log_likelihood_odom + log_likelihood_lidar

but we usually use one sensor as a measure, and another to predict. what I believe is true?

like using lidar data to predict relative movement,combined with odometry data to calculate log_likelihood, so the log_likelihood_total can not be gotten.


I do not know how back_end is sensor agnostic (back-end and relies on an abstract representation
of the data which is sensor agnostic.)

